# Show database value(float) to C# in label as float or double?

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, ado.net

How can I show a database value(float) to C# in label as float or double? I already figure out how to display it as a string but can't get it to display double. I tried `.ToString("00.00)";` or `.ToString("#0.00");` and get an error "No overload for method 'To String' takes 1 arguments.".

```
private void pos_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=DESKTOP-39SPLT0;Initial Catalog=SalesandInventory;Integrated Security=True");
            con.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand("select * from tblProduct", con);
            SqlDataReader reader = cmd1.ExecuteReader();
            reader.Read();
            lblEspSing.Text = reader["pPrice"].ToString();
            reader.Read();
            lblEspDou.Text = reader["pPrice"].ToString();
        }
```

Comment: `reader["pPrice"]` returns just an object, you need to cast it to the correct type (and watch out for nulls)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you need to cast it first

```
((float) reader["pPrice"]).ToString("00.00");
```

Comment: Good catch. Just fix it like this `ToString("00.00")` so that it compiles.

Comment: I got the error "InvalidCastException was unhandled" and the _lblEspSing_ was highlighted blue. I don't know that highlight means sorry.

Comment: @S.Akbari fixed

Comment: @ChresAbte check your database type. If its a float this should work. If its a double(real(53)) then you need to cast it as double. If its a varchar then you need to do string format

Comment: float on my database @Steve

Comment: @ChresAbte if you do a reader["pPrice"].GetType().ToString() what do you get?

Comment: @Steve it prints on the label System.Double

Comment: Steve it works if the cast is double! I don't know why but thank you.

Comment: @ChresAbte it prints System.Double because the type is a double and that's why when you try to cast it from an object type it fails. If you check the datatype of the column in database it should say real(53) instead of real(26) or float

Comment: it's float @Steve I double checked, I think it has something to do in .NET I read somewhere that you can't get the float from database to C# as float because of "I'm not sure the reason because I can't seem to find the link anywhere again" and has to be double. but I can still be wrong, but p.s. it's float in database

Answer (score 0):

You can convert it to a string, then use a string.format on it, using {0:N2}.
To format to two decimal places.

```
string.Format("{0:N2}", pPrice)
```

Then if you need 3 decimal places:

```
string.Format("{0:N3}", pPrice)
```

And so on.

You can also store the value in a string this way without worrying about precision and then convert your value where you are testing for comparison as string:

```
string strDecimalVal = Convert.ToString(pPrice);
```

Comment: I'm sorry I don't know where to put it.